# PowerShell - Invoke-Command on Remote Computer to Play Audio File Not Working for Windows 7

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I am trying to play an audio file remotely:

```
$RemoteComputer = 'Computer-Name'
$credential = Get-Credential
$path = 'C:\helpdeskbell.wav'

If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $RemoteComputer -Quiet)
{
     Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteComputer -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock { 
            $boolFileFound = (Test-Path C:\helpdeskbell.wav)
            if ($boolFileFound) {
                $soundplayer = New-Object Media.SoundPlayer 'C:\helpdeskbell.wav'
                $soundplayer.PlaySync()

                return "Found file - " + $boolFileFound
            } else {
                return "File doesn't exist on remote machine"
            }
        }
}
```

This code works in this scenario:

- Windows 7 PS v3.0 -> Windows 10 PS v5.0

And does not work in this scenario:

- Windows 7 PS v3.0 -> Windows 7 PS v3.0 (Attempting to "remote" to my own machine)
- Windows 7 PS v3.0 -> Windows 7 PS v2.0

By works I mean it plays the audio file.  By not working, it does enter the, "if ($boolFileFound)", statement and prints out, "Found file - True", but does not play any audio.  Why is this?